# Sort By Case: Where value LIKE, then POSITION

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a result set that needs to be sorted accordingly:

- if the column value is like 'Qwerty%', put it at the top, then sort by POSITION ascending
- if the column value is **not like** 'Qwerty%', add it under the above 'Qwerty%' result set and order them by POSITION ascending

For example, a result set as below:

```
 NAME                |    POSITION
 ---------------------------------
 entitlement         |    4
 threaten            |    1
 Qwerty Name         |    1
 Qwerty architecture |    7
 drown               |    6
 expectation         |    2
 clash               |    3
 foot                |    7
 ask                 |    10
 Qwerty structure    |    11
 Qwerty therapist    |    3
```

Should be returned in the order:

```
 NAME                |    POSITION
 ---------------------------------
 Qwerty Name         |    1
 Qwerty therapist    |    3
 Qwerty architecture |    7
 Qwerty structure    |    11
 threaten            |    1
 expectation         |    2
 clash               |    3
 entitlement         |    4
 drown               |    6
 foot                |    7
 ask                 |    10
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
SELECT NAME, POSITION FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY CASE NAME
    WHEN NAME LIKE 'Qwerty%' THEN CONCAT('A', NAME)
    ELSE POSITION END
```

But the result set comes back incorrectly as below

```
 NAME                |    POSITION
 ---------------------------------
 Qwerty Name         |    1
 Qwerty structure    |    11
 Qwerty therapist    |    3
 Qwerty architecture |    7
 threaten            |    1
 drown               |    6
 expectation         |    2
 ask                 |    10
 foot                |    7
 clash               |    3
 entitlement         |    4
```

As you can see, there is no sorting being done on the names that do not have 'Qwerty%' in them, and the ones that do are not sorting by POSITION correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *two* sorts levels in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT NAME, POSITION
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN NAME LIKE 'Qwerty%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    POSITION;
```

[image]

### Demo

Here is another, slightly more tidy, version of the query using `REGEXP` instead of a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT NAME, POSITION
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY
    NAME NOT REGEXP 'Qwerty',
    POSITION;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. With regards to the Regexp version vs the CASE version, which would you consider the faster of the two? Any advantages/disadvantages to either?

Comment: @DaveO'Dwyer Sorry for the delay in replying. I'm not sure which would win performance-wise, but both `LIKE` and `REGEXP` are doing functionally very similar things.  They are both scanning the name string from the beginning, looking for a certain prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, POSITION, SUM (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE 'Qwerty%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Sort
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY Sort, POSITION
```